# How to make dropdown questions required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, survey

I have created a short survey with 10 questions. I would like to make all 10 questions a requirement before the user can click submit.  The questions are in dropdown format listed on the left dies of the page. How do I go about doing this?  I have listed a codepen below. Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/missybur/pen/gxzYbz)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Survey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="content" role="main">
  <header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a id="header_text" href="#">Keypath Survey</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scores</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Favorites</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <!-- /.main-header -->

  <div class="survey">
    <div class="grid-100">

      <form action="">
        <div class="contained">
          <div class="grid-100">
            </br>

            <fieldset>
              <div>
                <label for="">1. Mixtape put a bird on it sartorial?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">2. Williamsburg unicorn tumeric?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">3. Keytar raclette green juice?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">4. Edison bulb iceland af pug?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">5. Sriracha mumblecore typewriter?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">6. Tote bag shabby chic cred?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">7. Thundercats organic bushwick plaid?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">8. Vexillologist drinking vinegar food truck?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">9. Distillery tbh gastropub DIY austin?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">10. Godard thundercats raw denim four dollar?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-footer">
          <button class="button primary submit">Submit Survey</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="graph">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <span>&copy;2017 Keypath Surveys</span>
  </footer>

</body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html> 

.contained {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

label {
  background-color:;
}

.graph {
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid-100, .graph {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.grid-75 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #692f23;
    border: solid 2px #f2ce0f;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #f2ce0f;
    border-radius: 10%;

}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-nav {
display: flex;
}

.survey {
  display: flex;
}

.survey .grid-100 {
  flex: 2;
}


/* =================================
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ---- Navigation ---- */

.name {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #f2ce0f;
}
.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.name a,
.main-nav a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.main-nav a {
  font-size: .95em;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #093a58;
}
#header_text {
  color: #692f23;
}

/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */

.main-header {
  background-color: #f2ce0f ;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border: 4px solid #890d1a;
}
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-footer {
  background: #d9e4ea;
  padding: 2em 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* =================================
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .main-header,
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .main-header,
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    /*max-width: 1150px;*/
  }
}

/*Reset CSS */


html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}




var $selects = $("select"),
  data,
  ctx = $("#myChart"),
  config = {
    selected: 0,
    type: "pie",
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function(args) {
          var selected = function() {
            var out = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              out = out + data[i];
            }
            return out;
          };
          var percentage = Math.round(args.value / selected() * 100) + "%";
          $('#'+args.label).text(percentage);
          return percentage;
        },
        fontSize: 14,
        fontStyle: "bold",
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontFamily: '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'
      }
    },

    data: {
      labels: ["Verbal", "Non-verbal", "Written"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [0, 0, 0],
          backgroundColor: ["#a03021", "#f2ce0f", "#4d4d4d"]
        }
      ]
    }
  };

myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

$(".submit").on("click", function(e) {
  var results = { v: 0, n: 0, w: 0 },
    hasSelected = 0;
  e.preventDefault();
  $selects.each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      results[val]++;
      hasSelected = 1;
    }
  });
  if (hasSelected) {
    data = [];
    $.each(results, function(k, v) {
      data.push(v);
    });
  } else {
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  }
  config.data.datasets[0].data = data;
  myChart.update();
  localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the way you are doing things in your pen:

1. You set one of the option to be "selected". You should just put the default "Select One" as the top option, give it a value of "" and not give it the attribute "selected" so the HTML "required" can detect that nothing has been selected yet.
2. You do your processing (the graph drawing and stuffs) on the button click, instead of on form submit. Because of this, the process will run even if the form is not submitted correctly.

---

tldr; 
You should let all the `<option>` NOT selected, and give a value of "" for invalid option.

```
<select required name="" id="">
    <option value="" >Select One</option>
    ... other options
</select>
```

You should give your form an 'id' attribute:

```
...
<form id="myForm" action="">
...
```

And only process it on form submit:

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  // do your stuff here
  ...
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jackyef/pen/ZJoBzg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use default required attribute for

```html
<form>
  <p>What is your favorite fruit?</p>
  <p>
    <select name="fruit" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Orange</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried adding those, but they did not make the drop down options required.  Am I putting them in the wrong place? https://codepen.io/missybur/pen/gxzYbz